# MaterialUI - global font settings

Tags: material-ui

How do you change the default `16px` browser font-size to `10px` using Material UI? As I understand it, MUI uses Nomralize.css under the hood?

In the my theme file I have

```
export default createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      '@global': {
        html: {
          padding: '0',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  typography: {
    htmlFontSize: 10,
    fontSize: 8,
    fontFamily: [
      '-apple-system',
      'BlinkMacSystemFont',
      '"Segoe UI"',
      'Roboto',
      '"Helvetica Neue"',
      'Arial',
      'sans-serif',
      '"Apple Color Emoji"',
      '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
      '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
    ].join(','),
    fontWeight: 400,
  },
})
```

but I don't know if this is right..

My app is also wrapped with `CssBaseLine`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <App />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
```

Is this correct? I remember the 62.5% trick and trying to accomplish something similar I guess

Comment: Your code works fine [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-cori-6von5?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just [fine](https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#font-size) and for future reference use use [React DevTools](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/15/new-react-devtools.html) to verify if your properties really apply or not (after React DevTools setup look for the `ThemeProvider` props).